# Is "unlock or sign in and rate" correct grammar?

Tags: grammar

There are two options: '*unlock*' and '*sign in and rate*'.

Does the following sentence reflect the two options?

> Unlock or sign in and rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar is fine, but your two conjunctions are confusing.

You mean

> (unlock) or (sign in and rate)

But it could be interpreted as

> (unlock or sign in) and (rate)

You should restate this to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you very much. could you help me ? what is correct way? if I write like `(unlock) or (sign in and rate)` than not professional.

Comment: I do not want ().

Comment: Write a longer sentence.  Without any context I can't give you any better advice than that.

Comment: Another option is to use quotation marks to signal the beginning and end of each option: "Choose either 'unlock' or 'sign in and rate'."

Comment: I read it as "Unlock or sign in **to** rate". Do you also rate if you unlock? If so, I suggest what I wrote.

Comment: @iMerchant thank you very much. if unlock do not rate. there are two options, one is only 'unlock', another one is 'sign in and rate.'

Comment: @SvenYargs thank you very much. this is also very good option. Is there any way do not use any quotation marks?

Comment: Yes. If you have the ability to change typefaces or underline, you can say "Choose either _unlock_ or _sign in and rate_" or "Choose either <und>unlock</und> or <und>sign in and rate<und>."

Comment: @SvenYargs I got it. Thank you very much for your help.